# ImageButton push effect without changing image using ObjectAnimator

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, effects

The objective is giving some feedback to the user tapping an ImageButton, in the Onclick event. I know It can be done changing the image depending of the state of the button, but It's more difficult when you have too many different images loading in runtime.

I did this, but is not that pretty

```
public void homeButtonClick(View view) {

        ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 1f, 0.9f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 1.0f, 0.9f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleUpX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.9f, 1f);
        ObjectAnimator scaleUpY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0.9f, 1.0f);


        AnimatorSet scaling = new AnimatorSet();

        scaling.play(scaleUpX).with(scaleUpY).after(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);
        scaling.setDuration(100);
        scaling.start();


scaling.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContentActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });
```

after doing the animation it calls a new Activity

Comment: What the hell is this **$**?! In 4 years of Android programming, I've never seen that before!! And today I saw this twice...

Comment: what you mean @Vyger?, it's a simple question, if there is a better way of giving feedback I'm all eyes

Comment: What does **$** mean in Java? I'm curious. I come from another language (VB.NET and VB6 and Basic in all flavour before)... In 4 years of Android programming I never met this **$** in Java code for Android. Today, for the second time, I saw it in two different questions... But I really have no clue of what should it mean. So, I really can't read your code.

Comment: $ is not Java, read my question again, it says "javascript", i'm giving other languages examples, because I can't accomplish this in Java.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It really didn't make any sense to me. I can breathe again, now.

Comment: actually $ is from jquery, a JavaScript library

Comment: OK, in Android is much simpler. When you make your xml layout containing the ImageButton (or a Button or a TextView, ...)  -just set the android:onClick property to the name of a function. The function signature must be **public void** functionName(**View v**). You can assign this function to multiple buttons (or other controls, even of mixed types): just provide a switch... case on the v.getId(). Each case will correspond to a R.id.someId (R is a special class that holds all the ids of all objects in all your layouts and special files).

Comment: mmmm, that's not really my question, I know how to set an onClick, the question is on the "functionName(View v)" how to alter the imageButton to appear like it was tapped, I tried changing the view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); on ACTION_DOWN but it's not that pretty. But thanks for the effort =)